# Typo3 - Extbase CommandController for scheduler task

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

i ve created an empty extbase/fluid extension and added an ImportCommandController for a scheduler task. For some reason i am not able to load that task in my scheduler. Please note that i want to realise my task via CommandController (http://wiki.typo3.org/CommandController_In_Scheduler_Task) and **NOT** via \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask.

**ext_localconf.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
die('Access denied.');
}

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] = 'VENDORx\\Sched\\Command\\ImportCommandController';
```

**Classes/Command/ImportCommandController.php**

```
<?php
    namespace VENDORx\Sched\Command;


    /**
     *
     *
     * @package Sched
     * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU General Public License, version 3 or later
     *
     */

    class ImportCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController {

        public function importCommand($commandIdentifier= NULL) {

        echo 'command run';

        }
      }
?>
```

any idea whats missing??

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the phpdoc-comment of the `importCommand()`-method is missing. At least its contents are shown if you run `php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase help`, so it is interpreted.

Comment: I took your code, added an `ext_emconf.php`, installed the extension - and it works fine (i.e. the new task appears in the dropdown). I did not add an Annotation to `importCommand` as suggested by @Jost and @Daniel. I'm using Windows 7 and - unlike you - Typo3 7.5.0.

Comment: ... actually running your task requires the mentioned Annotation, though. Without it, I get the following error message: 'Execution of task "Extbase CommandController Task (extbase)" failed with the following message: The argument type for parameter $commandIdentifier of method [...]->importCommand() could not be detected.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jost already mentioned you neet proper Annotations:

```
/**
 * @param integer $commandIdentifier 
 */
public function importCommand($commandIdentifier = NULL) {
    $this->outputLine('command run');
}
```

Comment: i ve modifed my CommadController Class but i still can't "use" it. I am  not able to add it through the T3 scheduler.  I ve made a screenshot of the scheduler BE. http://i.imgur.com/j6VZ0rK.png

Comment: the yellow marked dropdown does NOT contain my importCommand. i must be missing something.

Comment: Is your Extension installed? ;)

Comment: In my case it was the autoloading. Clearing the autoload cache or just uninstall/reinstall the extension helped.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Extbase-CommandController-Task" in dropdown
You'll get another select field on the bottom where you can find your "ImportCommand" select and save